# How to animate a hidden div to show using "animate.css" and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have been looking around on the internet but can't find anything about it.
My goal is to show div#manis:

```
<div id="manis">
Menu here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
display: none;
```

.. by using an animation inside the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) plugin.
How can I go around this?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain what you've already done in your attempt to get this to work. Using it looks pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

**Animate a hidden div to show using JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showhide(yourid) {
      if (document.getElementById) {
        var div-id = document.getElementById(id);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
          $(divs[i]).fadeOut("slow");
        }
        $(div-id).fadeIn("slow");
      }
      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to show div#manis

You really don't need a third party library for this.

If you use plain vanilla CSS @keyframes, you can do it like this:

```css
.manis {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-radius: 50%;
opacity: 1;
transform: translate(-50px, -50px);
animation: showManis 6s linear;
}

@keyframes showManis {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
 33% {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="manis"></div>
```

The animation lasts 6 seconds.

For the first 2 seconds, nothing changes.

For the next 4 seconds, the div animates from being completely transparent to completely opaque.

Banzai.